# Removing portions of string in Pandas: not working + errors

Tags: python, pandas, replace, split

I have a pandas DataFrame named `full_list` with a string-variable column named `domains`. Part of a snip shown here

```
  domains
0 naturalhealth365.com
1 truththeory.com
2 themillenniumreport.com
3 https://www.cernovich.com
4 https://www.christianpost.com
5 http://evolutionnews.org
6 http://www.greenmedinfo.com
7 http://www.magapill.com8
8 https://needtoknow.news
```

I need to remove the https:// OR http:// from the website names.

I checked multiple pandas post on SO dealing with vaguely similar issues and I have tried all of these methods:

1. `full_list['domains'] = full_list['domains'].apply(lambda x: x.lstrip('http://'))`
   but that erronoeusly removes the letters t, h and p as well i.e. "truththeory.com" (index 1) becomes "uththeory.com"
2. `full_list['domains'] = full_list['domains'].replace(('http://', ''))` and this makes no changes to the strings AT ALL. Like before and after the line run, the values in `domains` stay the same
3. `full_list['domains'] = full_list['domains'].str.replace(('http://', ''))` gives the error `replace() missing 1 required positional argument: 'repl'`
4. `full_list['domains'] = full_list['domains'].str.lsplit('//', n=1).str.get(1)` makes the first 3 rows (index 0, 1, 2) `nan`

For the world of me, I am unable to see what is it that I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your third attempt is wrong; try without encapsulating arguments in tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with regex `^` for start of string and `[s]*` for optional `s`:

```
df['domains'] = df['domains'].str.replace(r'^http[s]*://', '', regex=True)
print (df)
                   domains
0     naturalhealth365.com
1          truththeory.com
2  themillenniumreport.com
3        www.cernovich.com
4    www.christianpost.com
5        evolutionnews.org
6     www.greenmedinfo.com
7        www.magapill.com8
8          needtoknow.news
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `str.replace` with regex like the following:

```
>>> df['domains'].str.replace('http(s|)://', '')
0       naturalhealth365.com
1            truththeory.com
2    themillenniumreport.com
3          www.cernovich.com
4      www.christianpost.com
5          evolutionnews.org
6       www.greenmedinfo.com
7          www.magapill.com8
8            needtoknow.news
Name: domains, dtype: object
>>>
```

Comment: `full_list['domains'] = full_list['domains'].apply(lambda x: x.lstrip('http://')) but that erronoeusly removes the letters t, h and p as well i.e. "truththeory.com" (index 1) becomes "uththeory.com"`

Comment: Use `strip` with caution; `strip` is not like replace. It removes _all_ characters. If a remaining string starts with h, t,p or s, they will also get removed, just as it did in row1 (it's missing head `t`)

Comment: @U-12 Forward: I did this. Check point 1 in the 'I tried the following' list

Comment: @Chris - Exactly. I faced that problem. I didn't know how to evade it.

Comment: @U12-Forward Please check the output you got, row #1 - I did this. I just used the lstrip with apply that's the only difference. We're getting the same issue I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @Chris Edited mine